# Why do I get only *false* from @PostMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have Measurement class and DTO for it.
Here's the class:

```
 @Data
        public class MeasurementDTO {
        @Column(name = "measurement_temp")
        private double temp;
    
        @Column(name = "measurement_raining")
        private boolean isRaining;
    
        @NotEmpty
        @NotNull
        private String sensorName;
        }
```

And controller for it:

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
    private ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> add(@RequestBody @Valid MeasurementDTO measurementDTO,
                                           BindingResult bindingResult){

        System.out.println(measurementDTO.isRaining()); // returns false only

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();

            List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();

            for (FieldError error : errors)
                errorMsg.append(error.getField())
                        .append(" - ")
                        .append(error.getDefaultMessage())
                        .append("; ");

            throw new MeasurementNotCreatedException(errorMsg.toString());
        }

        if(sensorService.getAll().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals(measurementDTO.getSensorName()))){
            Measurement measurement = convertToMeasurement(measurementDTO);
            measurement.setSensor(sensorService.getByName(measurementDTO.getSensorName()));

            measurementService.save(measurement);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else throw new SensorNotFoundException();


    }
```

I do POST requestes with Postman. Sample
{
"isRaining" : true,
"temp" : 24.0,
"sensorName" : "new sensor"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of isRaining to raining, ie

private boolean raining;

Lombok @Data might be getting confused because the convention for generated boolean getters is to prepend “is”.

Comment: I resolved it by *@JsonProperty* on DTO isRaining. I think this could be an answer too